# How to install development files for antlr?

Tags: fedora-15, installation-package

How do I install header files for antlr (specifically I need files like antlr/config.hpp and antlr/AST.hpp) without having to install from source (basically from an rpm) for Fedora 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Just need the package antlr-C++.x86_64.